# Xen and HyperVM build question on os template

Tags: xen, virtual-machines, virtual-drive

I recently built a server with hypervm and xen, now i know xen from command line, but hypervm ties into our whmcs and so its a requirement, however my question is this, when i build a new o/s template my partition table is gone, and i know why, but i was wondering if anyone has built anything in hypervm for adding in partition tables, so i dont have to reinvent the wheel :).

i can do it command line in the created vm with fdisk, and i have tracked down the creation scripts for hypervm but i am unsure if these insert directly into the machine as it looks like a lot of the things it does are externalized and are for xen to assign things like ip address etc..

oh and on an aside when i go in to modify the .cnf file to change the boot disk from cdrom to drive on windows when i boot using hypervm it overwrites my setting again..frustrating as heck, i've been trying to track down where in the code it does this, has anyone else had this problem and if so how did you fix it if you did?

Answer (score 0):

if Windows you need the template installed with VNC and there are no other solution right now
:)